# Add year and month when exporting a dataset with SAS EG

Tags: variables, sas, filenames

in SAS EG I need to export some datasets as part of a process flow, adding the year and month to each filename (in Excel format). For example, table1, when exported, should be named table1_yyyymm. I have created a variable named "Period", which is populated with the year and month, based on the current date, but I need to "insert" this variable when defining the filename, otherwise I will always get the same name every time (monthly) I try to export these datasets.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Show the code you are currently using.  In particular the code that is used to name the Excel file.  For example if you are using ODS EXCEL statement show that code.  If you are using LIBNAME statement show that code. If you are using PROC EXPORT then show that code.

Comment: Are you using tasks or code? You create a macro variable out of the 'variable' and add that in to the task/code. Exactly how depends on how you created the variable and where it's stored and how it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following into your code or tasks where you provide the name.

Task: Output data set name = table1_%sysfunc(date(), yymmn6.)

Code:

```
proc export data=myData outfile="......_%sysfunc(date(), yymmn6.).xlsx" dbms=xlsx replace;
run;
```